# Redirecting printf to file in awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a simple bash script.

It's purpose is to monitor http access log file (test.log) and output to a file (out.log) the updated hit rate:

```
  stdbuf -o0 tail -f test.log | awk -F'[ "]+' '{
  ipcount[$1]++;
  print "test" > "out.log"; #Truncate out.log
  for (i in ipcount) {
        printf "%15s - %d\n", i, ipcount[i] >> "out.log";
        printf "%15s - %d\n", i, ipcount[i] }
}'
```

The main logic works. my only problem is the redirection to "out.log" that doesn't seem to work.
The last printf outputs the expected result to the standard output.
But the other two printf do not output anything to "out.log", and I cannot figure out why.
out.log has all permissions (777)

Comment: What if you remove quotes arround output file, e.g. just `printf "text" >> output.log`?

Comment: This is an `awk` issue, not a `bash` issue.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just redirect all the output of AWK to a file?

Comment: @unixarmy - when trying without the quotes, I get syntax error on the '.'(dot) that separates the filename and the extension.

Comment: @Soren , notice that before the loop I want to truncate the file, and append to in inside the loop.

Comment: @Yan4321 - I've been able to replicate your issue.  For some reason, the `print "text" > "out.log"` only truncates `out.log` **the first time**, then every subsequent call appends to it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
tail -f test.log | awk -F'[ "]+' -v out_file="out.log" '{
    val_count[$1]++
    print "" > out_file

    for (i in val_count) {
        printf "%15s - %d\n", i, val_count[i] >> out_file
        printf "%15s - %d\n", i, val_count[i]
    }

    close(out_file)
}'
```

(Note: I moved the output file definition to the command line to hopefully reduce repetition.)

Your original version has one fatal issue: `print "" > "out.log"` only truncates `out.log` the **first** time it's called.  All subsequent calls to it will simply append to it because it's already open.  As a secondary issue, awk likes to buffer output, so the contents will only be flushed intermittently.

To fix this, we need to `close` the file after each iteration.  This forcefully flushes the output to `out.log` and forces the `>` redirection to re-truncate the file on the next iteration.  If you didn't need to truncate each iteration, a simple `fflush(out_file)` would suffice.

---

To illustrate the issue more clearly...

This results in an `output.txt` that has **multiple** lines because it is truncated just once (the first iteration):

```
ls -l | awk '{ print "This file has many lines" > "output.txt"; }'
```

This results in an `output.txt` with a **single** output line because it is truncated multiple times:

```
ls -l | awk '{ print "This file has one line" > "output.txt"; close("output.txt"); }'
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you for the solution and the explanation. this solution worked for me. though on my environment, the initial code resulted in **no** output in out.log, which is different than what you experienced on your environment. anyway I won't forget to close a file handle the next time ;)

Comment: @Yan4321 - Ah, the other snag then would be that awk likes to buffer output (unless the output is going to a terminal).  To fix that, you'd need to `fflush` the file or stream.